# Convert Date String to Date object in Kotlin? How to calculate number of days between today and specific date in Kotlin?

Tags: android, date, kotlin

Part 1:
I have date as string in the following format: "2020-10-15T22:54:54Z"
I have to convert it into date object.
Tried the following:

```
val dateString = "2020-10-15T22:54:54Z"
val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
val updatedAtDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter)
val today = LocalDateTime.now()
println("Updated At: $updatedAtDate")
```

Gives the following error: "Unknown pattern letter: T"

Part 2:
Once I have the date object from above, I have to calculate the difference between today (Current Date) and the above date. How to do it in Kotlin?

Comment: The `T` is a literal, which means you have to escape it in your pattern using single quotes like `'T'`.

Comment: Tried that. It gives the following error: "Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-10-15T22:54:54Z' could not be parsed at index 0"

Comment: Well, that's obviously caused by the first character of your pattern. I suggest you have a look at which symbols are actually available (*Hint: percentage symbol isn't*) at the [JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). In this special case (your `dateString`), there's no need for a formatter, but you need an intermediate step if you want the date part only (`LocalDate` only has year, month and day, no time of day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr You don't need to create a custom formatter…

… for the `val dateString = "2020-10-15T22:54:54Z"` here, it is formatted in an ISO standard. Therefore, you can simply do this (if you want a `LocalDate`, just year, month and day):

```kotlin
val thatDate: LocalDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString).toLocalDate()
```

---

### Fully adressing all the aspects of your post:

You can utilize a `java.time.Period.between(LocalDate, LocalDate)` in order to calculate the difference between two `LocalDate`s. You only have to make sure the older date is the first argument, otherwise you will get a negative result. Here's a full example:

```kotlin
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Period

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val dateString = "2020-10-15T22:54:54Z"
    // create an OffsetDateTime directly
    val thatDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString)
                                      // and extract the date
                                      .toLocalDate()
    // get the current day (date only!)
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    // calculate the difference in days and make sure to get a positive result
    val difference = if (today.isBefore(thatDate))
                        Period.between(today, thatDate).days
                     else
                         Period.between(thatDate, today).days
    // print something containing both dates and the difference
    println("[$today] Updated At: $thatDate, difference: $difference days")
}
```

Output at Dec 10, 2021:

```
[2021-12-10] Updated At: 2020-10-15, difference: 25 days
```